# it is possible to load app when onclick dial button in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, phone-call

i created simple app in which a one TextBox to type password to verify user.

1)my doubt is when i click a dial button in android my app should opens and asks a password to allow user to call.

if it is possible,help me

because why i am doing this thing to improve security by indicating a intruder when he trying to make a call to someone using my mobile.

@android